# ContactsComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angular

**I am going to develop a simple Angular 4 application. I have created a project with services, using Angular CLI and added service to the app using 'ng generate service ' command as following.**

***contactService :***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http} from '@angular/http';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/http';
import  "rxjs/add/operator/map" ;

@Injectable()
export class ContactService {

  constructor (public http: Http) {}

 getContact() {

  return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/contacts').map(resp=>resp.json());


}
```

***contacts.component :***

```
import { Component, Injector, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http} from '@angular/http';
import  "rxjs/add/operator/map" ;
import { ContactService } from '../services/contact.service';
// import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-c',
  templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css'],
  providers: [ContactService]
})


export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {
pageContact:any;
motCle:string = "";
  constructor(public http: Http, public contactservice : ContactService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.contactservice.getContact().subscribe(data => {this.pageContact = data},err=>{console.log(err)});

  }


}
```

***AppModule :***

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Http} from '@angular/http';
// import { ContactService } from '../services/contact.service';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ContactsComponent } from './contacts/contacts.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';


const appRoutes : Routes = [
  {path : 'about', component : AboutComponent},
  {path : 'contacts', component : ContactsComponent},
  {path : '', redirectTo : '/about', pathMatch:'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ContactsComponent,
    AboutComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,

  ],

  // providers: [ContactService],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[image: Error Message]

**Am I doing anything wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Configure a proxy for your API calls with Angular CLI

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong accessing:

```
@Injectable()
export class ContactService {

constructor (public http: HttpClient) {} //Not Http

getContact() {

  return  this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/contacts')
    .map(resp=>resp.json());
 }
```

If you are using Angular 4.3+ , you are no need to use HttpModule, Http, use HttpClientModule, HttpClient instead of this

Comment: Hello DmitriyKhirniy, thank you for your reply
I just tested, unfortunately it does not work

Comment: Try to use import import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'; instead of  {HttpClient} from '@angular/http';